# no detecta el elemento

Tags: php, html, jquery

buen dia a todos
tengo un html y usando un js, pero resulta que en el js estoy usando un load para insertar otro html, pero no me detecta los elementos de ese otro html

mi php principal es este

```
<?php 
    $includeController = 'includes/controllers/forms/forms.controller.php';
    if ((include_once $includeController) == FALSE) echo 'ERROR al conectar el controlador';
    $formControl = new FormsController();
    $listForms = $formControl->searchForms();
    // --------------------------- //
  $includeController = 'includes/controllers/Laboratory/Laboratory.controller.php';
  if ((include_once $includeController) == FALSE) echo 'ERROR al conectar el controlador';
  $orderControl = new LaboratoryController();
  $listLaboratory = $orderControl->ListLaboratory();
  // ----- Include del controlador ----- //
  $includeController = 'includes/controllers/OrderMedical/ordermedical.controller.php';
  if ((include_once $includeController) == FALSE) echo 'ERROR al conectar el controlador';
  // ----- Listado de templates ----- //
  $OrderMedicalControl = new OrderMedicalController();
  $SelectedTemplate = $OrderMedicalControl->viewTemplate();
  // ------------LISTADO DE PACIENTES--------------- //
  $includeController = 'includes/controllers/users/users.controller.php';
  if ((include_once $includeController) == FALSE) echo 'ERROR al conectar el controlador';
  $patientControl = new UsersController();
  $listPatient = $patientControl->viewpatientuser();
  // ------------LISTADO DE GRUPOS HECTAREALES--------------- //
  $includeController = 'includes/controllers/grouphectareal/grouphectareal.controller.php';
  if ((include_once $includeController) == FALSE) echo 'ERROR al conectar el controlador';
  $GroupHectarealControl = new GroupHectarealController();
  $listGroup = $GroupHectarealControl->searchGroupHectareal();
  $listGroupandspecialty = $GroupHectarealControl->viewgroupeandspecialty();
   // ------------LISTADO DE ESPECIALIDADES--------------- //
  $includeController = 'includes/controllers/route/route.controller.php';
  if ((include_once $includeController) == FALSE) echo 'ERROR al conectar el controlador';
  $SpecialtyControl = new RouteController();
  $listSpecialty = $SpecialtyControl->searchSpecialty();
  $listRoute = $SpecialtyControl->searchRoute();
  $listRoutePatient = $SpecialtyControl->searchroutepatient();
    // ------------LISTADO DE CONSULTORIOS CON SEDES--------------- //
  $includeController = 'includes/controllers/rooms/rooms.controller.php';
  if ((include_once $includeController) == FALSE) echo 'ERROR al conectar el controlador';
  $RoomControl = new RoomController();
  $listRooms = $RoomControl->viewRoomsandentitys();
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/carepatien.js"></script>
<div class="card border-0 shadow-sm">
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="tab-content" id="user-tabs-content">
            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="users" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="users" tabindex="0">
                <div class="row">
                    <input type="hidden" id="idformato" name="idformato"/>
                    <input type="hidden" id="selectdocuments" name="selectdocuments"/>
                    <input type="hidden" id="iddoctormodal" name="iddoctormodal" class="form-control">
          <input type="hidden" id="idcitamodal" name="idcitamodal" class="form-control">
          <input type="hidden" id="idconsultoriomodal" name="idconsultoriomodal" class="form-control">
          <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="iddoctororder" name="iddoctororder" placeholder="Doctor" readonly>
          <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="namedoctor" name="namedoctor" placeholder="Doctor" readonly>
          <input type="hidden" id="namepatientmodal" name="namepatientmodal" class="form-control" readonly>
          <input type="hidden" id="idpatientattendmodal" name="idpatientattend" class="form-control" readonly>
          <input type="hidden" name="generalodontogram" id="generalodontogram">
          <input type="hidden" id="backgroundcolor">
                    <input type="hidden" id="templateselect">
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                            <select class="form-select" id="selectformpatient" onchange="cargarpestañas(this)">
                                <option>Select</option>
                                <?php
                                    foreach($listForms as $key=>$value){
                                        echo'
                                            <option value="'.$value['idformato'].'">'.$value['nombreFormato'].'</option>
                                        ';
                                    }
                                ?>
                            </select>
                            <label for="idpatientattendmodal">Select Form</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
          <div class="col">
            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
              <select class="form-select" id="selectspecialty" onchange="cargararbol(this)">
                <option>Select</option>
                <?php
                  foreach($listSpecialty as $key=>$value){
                    echo'
                      <option value="'.$value['idruta'].'">'.$value['nombre'].'</option>
                    ';
                  }
                ?>
              </select>
              <label for="idpatientattendmodal">Select Specialty</label>
            </div>
          </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dateorder" placeholder="Date Order" onchange="dateorder(this)">
              <input type="date" class="form-control" id="dateorderdos" name="dateorder"  value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d') ?>">
              <label for="dateorder">Date Order</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col mb-1">
            <div class="px-2">
              <label>Laboratory</label>
              <div class="form-floating pt-3">
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="SelectLaboratory" id="radioGender1" value="internal">
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="radioGender1">Internal</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="SelectLaboratory" id="radioGender2" value="External">
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="radioGender2">External</label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div>
              <h5 class="c-secondary">Recommendations</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush" id="ulrecomendaciones">
              <div id="recomendacionesdiv"></div>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <ul id="tapsdeformularios" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                <li class="nav-item" role="presentation" id="pestanaform">
                  <button class="nav-link active" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#medicalorder" id="Buttonmedicalorder" data-content-right="medicalorder" role="medicalorder" aria-controls="Forms" aria-selected="true">Medical Order</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="card border-0 shadow-sm">
              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="tab-content" id="user-tabs-content-documents">
                   <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="medicalorder" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="medicalorder" tabindex="0">
                    <div id="ordermedicalselect"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var listapacientes = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($listPatient); ?>');
    var listagrupohectareal = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($listGroup); ?>');
    var listaespecialidadesporgrupo = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($listGroupandspecialty); ?>');
    listadorightrecomendaciones(listapacientes,listagrupohectareal,listaespecialidadesporgrupo);
    var ordermedical = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($SelectedTemplate); ?>');
    var listaconsultoriosyentidades = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($listRooms); ?>');
    ordermedicalfunction(ordermedical,listapacientes,listaconsultoriosyentidades);
  });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function Selectespecialty(option){
    var listRoutePatient = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($listRoutePatient); ?>');
    var listarutaintegral = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($listRoute); ?>');
    Selectespecialtytwo(option,listRoutePatient,listarutaintegral);
  };

</script>
```

este es mi js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#dateorderdos").hide();
  $("#dateorder").datepicker();
  const fecha = new Date();
  const mes = (fecha.getMonth())+1;
  const dia = fecha.getDate();
  const ano = fecha.getFullYear();
  $('#dateorder').val(mes+'/'+dia+'/'+ano);
  var IdDoctor = sessionStorage.getItem("IdDoctor");
  var namepatient = sessionStorage.getItem("namepatient");
  var idpatient = sessionStorage.getItem("idpatient");
  var idappoinment = sessionStorage.getItem("idappoinment");
  var namedoctor = sessionStorage.getItem("namedoctor");
  var idria = sessionStorage.getItem("idria");
  var idspecialty = sessionStorage.getItem("idspecialty");
  var nameria = sessionStorage.getItem("nameria");
  var nombreespecialidad = sessionStorage.getItem("nombreespecialidad");
  var idconsultorio = sessionStorage.getItem("idconsultorio");
  $("#iddoctormodal").val(IdDoctor);
  $("#idcitamodal").val(idappoinment);
  $("#idpatientattendmodal").val(idpatient);
  $("#namepatientmodal").val(namepatient);        
  $("#namedoctor").val(namedoctor);
  $("#iddoctororder").val(IdDoctor);
  $("#selectspecialty").val(idspecialty);
  $("#namespecialtyorder").val(nombreespecialidad);
  $("#idconsultoriomodal").val(idconsultorio);
});
//FUNCION PARA CARGAR LA ORDEN MEDICA SELECCIONADA
function ordermedicalfunction(ordermedical,listapacientes,listaconsultoriosyentidades){
  var idtemplate = ordermedical[0].idtemplate;
  var color = ordermedical[0].colortemplate;
  var rgbaBgColor = 'rgba('+color+',var(--bs-bg-opacity))';
   $('.bg-custom').css('background-color', rgbaBgColor);
  switch(idtemplate){
  case 1:
    $('#ordermedicalselect').load('./vistas/modules/InvoicesOrder/invoice_1.html');
    break;
  case 2:
    $('#ordermedicalselect').load('./vistas/modules/InvoicesOrder/invoice_2.html');
    break;
  case 3:
    $('#ordermedicalselect').load('./vistas/modules/InvoicesOrder/invoice_3.html')
    break;
  }
  background(rgbaBgColor,idtemplate,listapacientes,listaconsultoriosyentidades);
};
//FUNCION PARA EL FONDO DE LA ORDEN MEDICA
function background(rgbaBgColor,idtemplate,arraylistapacientes,arraylistaconsultoriosyentidades){
  window.onload = function(){
    console.log(document.getElementById('templatenamepatient'))
  };
  console.log(rgbaBgColor)
  $('.bg-custom').css('background-color', rgbaBgColor);
  var listapacientes = arraylistapacientes;
  var listaconsultoriosyentidades = arraylistaconsultoriosyentidades;
  var idconsultorio = document.getElementById('idconsultoriomodal').value;
  var namedoctor = $('#namedoctor').val();
  var iddoctororder = $('#iddoctororder').val();
  var idpatient = $('#idpatientattendmodal').val();
  var namepatient = $('#namepatientmodal').val();
  for(var i = 0; i < listapacientes.length; i++){
    if(listapacientes[i]['iduser'] == idpatient){
      var nombrepaciente = listapacientes[i]['nombre']+' '+listapacientes[i]['primerapellido']+' '+listapacientes[i]['segundoapellido'];
      var idpaciente = listapacientes[i]['identificacion'];
      var edad = calcularedadpaciente(listapacientes[i]['dob']);
      var fecha = listapacientes[i]['dob'];
      var genero = listapacientes[i]['genero'];
      var telefono = listapacientes[i]['telefono'];
      var tiposangre = listapacientes[i]['tiposangre'];
      var rh = listapacientes[i]['rh'];
      var ciudad = listapacientes[i]['provider'];
    }
  }
  for(var j = 0; j < listaconsultoriosyentidades.length; j++){
    if(listaconsultoriosyentidades[j]['idconsultorio'] == idconsultorio){
      var direccion = listaconsultoriosyentidades[j]['direccionsede'];
      var consultorio = listaconsultoriosyentidades[j]['nombreconsultorio'];
      var nombresede = listaconsultoriosyentidades[j]['nombresede'];
    }
  }
  console.log(namepatient+' - '+genero+' - '+fecha+' - '+idpaciente+' - '+edad+' - '+telefono)
  switch(idtemplate){
    case 1:
      console.log('template 1')
      $('#templatenamepatient').append(namepatient);
      $('#templategenderpatient').append(genero);
      $('#templatedatepatient').append(fecha);
      $('#templateidpatient').append(idpaciente);
      $('#templateagepatient').append(edad);
      $('#templatephonepatient').append(telefono);
      $('#templatenameentity').append(nombresede);
      $('#templateaddressentity').append(direccion);
      $('#templatenameroom').append(consultorio);
      break;
    case 2:
      $('#templatenamedoctor').append(namedoctor);
      $('#templateiddoctor').append(iddoctororder);
      $('#templatenamepatient').append(nombrepaciente);
      $('#templateidpatient').append(idpaciente);
      $('#templateagepatient').append(edad);
      $('#templatedatepatient').append(fecha);
      $('#templategenderpatient').append(genero);
      $('#templatenameentity').append(nombresede);
      $('#templateaddressentity').append(direccion);
      $('#templatenameroom').append(consultorio);
      break;
    case 3:
      $('#templatenamedoctor').append(namedoctor);
      $('#templateiddoctor').append(iddoctororder);
      $('#templateidpatient').append(idpaciente);
      $('#templatenamepatient').append(nombrepaciente);
      $('#templategenderpatient').append(genero);
      $('#templateagepatient').append(edad);
      $('#templatephonepatient').append(telefono);
      $('#templaterhpatient').append(rh);
      $('#templatebloodtypepatient').append(tiposangre);
      $('#templateproviderpatient').append(ciudad);
      $('#templatenameentity').append(nombresede);
      $('#templateaddressentity').append(direccion);
      $('#templatenameroom').append(consultorio);
      break;
    }
}
```

el load me carga muy bien, pero no me detecta los elementos para poder enviar los datos que requiero, es decir que el switch case que tengo con los append no estan haciendo absolutamente nada

ya he cambiado de posicion el script para usar el js al inicio, al final y nada, ya e usado windows onload y nada, ya no se que hacer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tiene que organizar , analizar mejor tu código Javascript,
1 - Los Elementos javascript por lo regular los cargas al final de tu html
2 - si te das cuenta debe haber alguna función mal en tu controlador, o debes
separar la logica de mejor manera, llamando primero toda la logica de los controladores ,  posteriormente los estilos - funcionalidad, que desea cargar, puesto
que tiene 2 funciones ONREADY en tu html ,que estas a su vez , dicho de una forma simple : no sabe javascript, que documento quieres que cargue primero

opción A si tus controladores =>

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  **$(document).ready(function()**{
    var listapacientes = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($listPatient); ?>');
    var listagrupohectareal = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($listGroup); ?>');
```

.........

ó opción B tu archivo con funciones /estilos ,etc =>

```
**$(document).ready(function()**{
  $("#dateorderdos").hide();
  $("#dateorder").datepicker();
  const fecha = new Date();
  const mes = (fecha.getMonth())+1;
  const dia = fecha.getDate();
  const ano = fecha.getFullYear();
  $('#dateorder').val(mes+'/'+dia+'/'+ano);
```